# mongodb query return simple array

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine

How can I make mongodb return results in a simple array?

Ex:

My first query:

```
$user_ids = $dm->createQueryBuilder('AcmeBundle:Users')
->hydrate(false)
->select('_id')
->getQuery()
->execute();
```

My second query:

```
$no_credit = $dm->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Places')
->createQueryBuilder('places')
->distinct('_id')
->field('visited.users')
->in($user_ids)
->getQuery()
->count();
```

How can I achieve this when the first query won't return an array of MongoID objects?

Comment: by simple array, you mean numeric array?

Comment: I must admit I do not symfony however I believe it returns an implmentation of `MongoCursor` as such getting the cursor object and doing `iteratortoarray` or something similar will solve the problem in a hackish way.

Comment: by "simple array" I mean an array(). Since that's how in() works:  `field('wtvr')->in(array(,,,))` .

Comment: Ok I see multiple problems here now. You will need to filter out your first query by iterating through it and forming the new array in which to do the `in()`. It is the only way due to how Mongo returns the results.

Comment: @Sammaye Please write your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Done glad to have helped

Comment: Could someone please reformat and properly set up this question, because I do not understand what is required....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must admit I do not symfony however I believe it returns an implmentation of MongoCursor as such getting the cursor object and doing iteratortoarray or something similar will solve the problem in a hackish way.

Comment: While this didn't exactly solve my problem, it does solve similar issues. By doing array_keys() I can get the "raw data" that is stored on the results. But as your second comment suggests, "You will need to filter out your first query by iterating through it and forming the new array in which to do the in()".